# Meta-Analysis help with next steps

Tags: r, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am conducting a meta-analysis on literature that is comparing two platforms to each other. I've extracted statistics from the relevant comparison and for the relevant dvs (response time, accuracy). From this I was able to compute the effect sizes (cohen's d). Does it make sense to turn an anova on these data. For example, something like this: aov(effectSize ~ platform)

The platform variable indicates which platform showed a benefit for that specific study. So if one study has a cohen's d = .98 and the direction of the effect indicated that response time was faster with platform 1 than platform 2, then I indicated in my datafile platform 1 next to the effect size column.

[image]

I think I have a disconnect about what kind of analysis to run after I've computed the effect sizes from each study. Any references or advice would be great!

Comment: You've said it - you need to do a meta-analysis. For that you (probably) need to use a package (in R? It looks like you're using R) that does meta-analysis. I like metafor.

Comment: Hi @JeremyMiles - my question pertains to what the next step is after I've computed the desired effect sizes for each study. For example, I tired to use the meta pagakage in R but it doesn't have a variable for cohen's d -- it has one for pearons r but we are wanting to report cohen's d or hedges g.

Comment: You do a meta-analysis. One option is to use the rma() function in the metafor package: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:input_to_rma_function (yi is d, vi is variance of d).

Answer (score 0):

For a meta-analysis of this sort, the idea is to combine the effect size information from your disparate samples into one measure for the effect size.  The conventional protocol here would be to estimate the confidence interval for your effect.  This would be done separately for each measure.

While not ideal, you could then observe how near or far apart your confidence intervals are from each other.

Also, as a word of advice, be sure to carefully check the order of subtraction used to calculate the effect sizes (as it is not uncommon to see effect sizes always reported as positive values...where the direction of the difference is meant to be inferred from the context of the problem or journal article).